# Wrong offset for UITextView when new line entered

Tags: ios, swift, textview

This is how it looks in my app when I press enter after some text:

[image]

Why it moves scroll at wrong place? How to fix it?

This is what I do when `textDidChange`:

```
textViewHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = min(contentSize.height, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

first set,

```
  self.yourTextView.scrollEnabled = false
```

initially.

Then when your `textview` reach at pick point of height (i.e. maximum height) then

```
    self.yourTextView.scrollEnabled = true
```

then when your `textview` again reach to minimum heigh then again set to false and again yes when reach at maximum height.

Try this if it will work!!

and also try `layoutIfNeeded` on superview of your `textView` after changing `constant`

Answer (score 0):

set minimum and maximum height for textview ::

```
 @IBOutlet var textViewHeightConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
        let minTextViewHeight = CGFloat(33)
        let maxTextViewHeight = CGFloat(70)

        func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

            var height = ceil(txtViewChat.contentSize.height) // ceil to avoid decimal

            if (height < minTextViewHeight) { 
                height = minTextViewHeight
            }
            if (height > maxTextViewHeight) { 
                height = maxTextViewHeight
            }
            if height != textViewHeightConst.constant { 
                textViewHeightConst.constant = height

            }
        }
```